# Print lines starting from bottom in ruby

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a variable `arr` in ruby that holds a 300+ line of string. And every time I view the said variable, it always prints out tons of lines. Is there a way in ruby that displays them and focuses on the last line? (Just like `tail` command).

Comment: Couldn't you just use `puts my_array[-10..-1]` which will print the last 10 lines?

Comment: I would like to contribute this feature to the `pry` gem so that when I try to do a `hist -tail <more than history line number>` it would be just like the when you invoke the `tail` method in bash.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the last 3 lines, do this: `arr.split[-3,3]`

Here's an example:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> arr = "foo
irb(main):002:0" bar
irb(main):003:0" baz
irb(main):004:0" 1
irb(main):005:0" 2
irb(main):006:0" 3
irb(main):007:0" 4
irb(main):008:0" 5
irb(main):009:0" 6
irb(main):010:0" 7
irb(main):011:0" 8
irb(main):012:0" 9
irb(main):013:0" 10
irb(main):014:0" the
irb(main):015:0" end
irb(main):016:0" "
=> "foo\nbar\nbaz\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\nthe\nend\n"
irb(main):017:0> arr.split[-3,3]
=> ["10", "the", "end"]
```

If your string is extremely large, and you have some knowledge about typical line lengths, and performance was an issue, and you can tolerate it being inaccurate on occasion, you might try copying out just the tail end, and then splitting it.  Something like this:

```
irb(main):019:0* arr[-20,20]
=> "\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\nthe\nend\n"
irb(main):020:0> arr[-20,20].split[-3,3]
=> ["10", "the", "end"]
irb(main):021:0>
```

So if these were web server log entries, they might run ~200 characters a line.  Let's say you want to show the last 3 lines.  Grab the last 1000 characters of the string, and you'll be be in pretty good shape most of the time.

Hope this helps!